# Instagram API Error: "You cannot like this media"

Tags: api, instagram

[DUPLICATE POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28477010/1830228)

I have an app where users can see pictures of other users who are using my app and like it when they want to. The problem is that many People are telling me that they can't like pictures even when they just downloaded my app for the first time and want to like something.

The error is:

```
Error message: {"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot like this media"}}
```

For example a picture gets 20 likes without a problem and after that it produces the error mentioned above when another user wants to like it. After some time (maybe a day) it works again for a few likes until the error comes back. My app is whitelisted but why this error happens?
The amount of likes before this error starts is different from user to user. It can also be that a pic from a completely new user of my app gets this error within the first like. Is it because the pic already had many likes before? Is Instagram using advanced imits for API-likes?

Comment: Possible duplicate (no accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929799/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076629/ ...actually just google for `"you cannot like this media"`. Plethora of relevant results, on SO and other sites.

Comment: not true...no one has solved that one yet...

Comment: Similar question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477010/instagram-you-cannot-like-this-media-400-status-code/28486546#28486546