# Instagram “You Cannot Like this Media” 400 status code

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-8, instagram, instagram-api

I am aware that the Instagram API was down a few hours ago, but it seems to be back up now. The problem is, when we post data to Instagram saying to like a specific photo, we get this error:

{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot like this media"}}
We have gotten this error before, but we don't understand why we are getting it. Keep in mind, we logged into an alternate account which means that account hasn't even liked the media yet.

If it helps at all to know, we are running the like command by requesting the url https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes with {media-id} being replaced by the image id, and we are including the user's access token in the body of the http request. This is obviously a post request

There is no Instagram documentation on why we would get this message. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you find any proper answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same thing and I found that there were three cases where I received this error:

1. **The photo has been deleted.** If you are caching media data and trying to like it later this could come up.
2. **The user is private.** You can't like a photo if the user is private and they haven't given you permission to follow them.
3. **You've done too much liking with the public API.** If you try to like a photo and find that it's neither deleted nor is the user private, then Instagram has put a temporary ban on your account from liking via the api. I'm not sure what triggers this other than excessive liking. You'll need to wait up to a week without making any high-volume likes via that access token for the timeout to expire (although you can to a test every once in a while to see if this timeout has expired).

Comment: ok but if i am using another Instagram like  app which use api  and like some photos than like work but in my app if i am change client id and secret it  and after that get new access token and like some photos than it not work for me why ? if Instagram has put a temporary ban than it also  not work in that am i right ? please help me

Comment: from what i've seen the ban is app-specific. access tokens are unique to a user/app combo so that's why your account can execute likes via a different app but not your own. Don't be a spammer - stay within the limits, wait out your ban, and then you should be back up and running. You might also want to make sure you're signing your headers properly, that will give you increased likes/hour http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/

Comment: What reasoning is behind setting their limits lower than their actual said limits? I liked 100 / hour and have had my liking ability suspended. Why not explicitly say what their actual cap is in their documentation? ..

Comment: in some case my account suspend only in 22 likes are you passing a ipaddress  in post?

Comment: yeah passing the IP address is part of signing the request according to their standards. If you do this you get an increased liking limit so it's worth it