# Instagram Api Requests Systematically Refused

Tags: python, json, urllib2, urllib, instagram-api

I have been using client id and auth token of instagram api for a while to make requests with urllib and json. Since a few days, any client id/auth token I create for an instagram account returns systematically "HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST" when I make a request, it can be for like, follow, or unfollow, it always returns this error. The script is Python 2.7 based.
It was working great before, and the keys created before this happened still work great! I tried to create new accounts and new keys from usa with proxies, but the error persist..

---

Here is the part of the code :

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7’
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent,
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded”

def likePicture(pictureId):
    liked = 0
    try:
        urlLike = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/%s/likes"
        values = {'access_token' : auth_token,
                  'client_id' : client_id}
        newLike = urlLike % (pictureId)
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(newLike,data,headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = response.read()
        dataObj = json.loads(result)
        liked = 1
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    return liked
```

---

The print e gives me systematically "HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST", even if the key is brand new and the account brand new. And this code is working like a charm on older keys (from a week ago).
Any idea or suggestion? Maybe blocked somehow by instagram because I created to many client id/auth token? If it is the case, how to do to resolve this situation? (I already tried to use different proxies, unsuccessful, so how would they track that?). If someone finds a solution to this problem I will be infinitely grateful to him! 
Cheers, Kevin

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477010/instagram-you-cannot-like-this-media-400-status-code answer your question?

Comment: Is your existing script short enough to post here?

Comment: Thom, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477010/instagram-you-cannot-like-this-media-400-status-code does not answer the question I think, because for me, even if I create a brand new account with a new key, I will get the 400 error at the first request, so no excess what so ever

Comment: Have you read the "Limits" API section? Make a request and read http headers (X-Ratelimit-Remaining and X-Ratelimit-Limit:) sent by API:
https://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

> You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad
>   Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app.
>   These errors are unrelated to rate limiting.

Have you read the "Limits" from API docs?
When calling Instagram API methods it send two HTTP headers:

- **X-Ratelimit-Remaining:** the remaining number of calls available to your app within the 1-hour window
- **X-Ratelimit-Limit:** the total number of calls allowed within the 1-hour window

So check if you've reached the limit.

Keep in mind that multiples calls in a short time window is considered abusive.

Read more:

- [Limits](https://instagram.com/developer/limits/)

**P.S:** *It's not necessary forge headers in order to make API calls! It isn't web scraping!*

Comment: Hi Felipsmartins, It is not a matter of limit because the error is given for any key I create on any Instagram account, since the first call. It is not like it works and then I reach the limit, the key is blocked since the beginning. I know the limits and the code is taking care of respecting it. It seems that I am blocked for spammy behavior, so any key I create is blocked, but if it is the case I would like to know how to resolve that matter. I just try to understand what produces that error.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean exactly with "P.S: It's not necessary forge headers in order to make API calls! It isn't web scraping!"? I should try to change the header? the request form?